# Show fields from other models (collections) in keystone.js admin UI?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, keystonejs

**I have two Models**

```
/**
 * Page Model
 * =============
 */

var Page = new keystone.List('Page');

Page.add({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    pid: { type: String, required: true , default:"123" },
    phone: { type: String },
    keyword : {type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'Keyword' , many: true},
    searchvol : {type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'Keyword' , many: true},
    pageType: { type: Types.Select, options: [
        { value: 'message', label: 'Just leaving a message' },
        { value: 'question', label: 'I\'ve got a question' },
        { value: 'other', label: 'Something else...' }
    ] },
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

Page.relationship({ path: 'keywords', ref: 'Keyword',    refPath: 'keyword' });
Page.relationship({ path: 'keywords', ref: 'Keyword',    refPath: 'searchvol' });
```

And the Keywords Model

```
/**
 * Keyword Model
 * =============
 */

var Keyword = new keystone.List('Keyword');

Keyword.add({
    //name: { type: String, required: true },
    searchvol: { type: String },
    keywordType: { type: Types.Select, options: [
        { value: 'message', label: 'brand' },
        { value: 'question', label: 'exact match' },
        { value: 'other', label: 'Something else...' }
    ] },
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

I want to include the search volume in the Admin UI so that I can use it sort and filter

however it seems to only be able to include the name field and if I remove that field it only shows the id.

So is the only way to fix this is to build a custom crud interface that handles my "Joins" or there exists a way to make it work with the current settings.

Here is the link to the documentation where I found some details about how to do this.
http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/#relationships

Answer (score 4):

@RaedMarji, Keystone always uses to `name` field to display a referenced relationship. However, in cases like yours, when you don't have `name` field, you can map an existing field to act like the model's name.

Just update your List definition as follows:

```
var Keyword = new keystone.List('Keyword', {
    map: { name: 'searchvol' }
});
```

Comment: I understand this, however how about if I want to show multiple values from the other collections, like name, search_text and type. which all belong to the same id.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear from your question. All I understood what that you wanted "to include the search volume in the Admin UI".  Unfortunately, that is not possible at the moment. I believe there is another related issue open at the moment.

Comment: yes I understand your confusion, and it seems so that there is no implementation to do this. which is weird in my opinion. however I think it can be done the same way the name has been done. maybe someone can look into it. and I will try to give a look a look myself maybe I can work it out.